# In App Purchases Sandbox Testing - Old sandbox users keep prompting

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am working on an iphone game with in app purchases. I'm trying to retrieve my sandbox user's previous purchases by calling restoreCompletedTransactions, but no callback is being fired.

I read online from some other people who have had similar issues to delete the sandbox user and try creating a new one. I tried deleting and creating new test users multiple times over the course of a month or so (some users report that it's apple's sandbox servers) but I have had zero luck.

Here's the strange thing, every time I'm prompted for my user credentials on my iphone when I make that restore call, I get prompted for **all of my previous sandbox accounts I've ever tried**. It's very weird, because I've deleted them from ITunesConnect and also signed out on app store on my IPhone settings.

I've also tried restoring my IPhone - didn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you add a transaction observer iOS will check the default Queue if there is any non completed transaction (which mean you didn't finish it) so it will show the alert box every time there is a transaction until you finish it even if you didn't do any action to add a new payment. so try to call finish transaction for all transactions which currently stuck on the queue.

Comment: How can you finish a transaction for a user that no longer exists?

Comment: OK. I got rid of most of them by hard coding a `finishTransaction` in `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`. They weren't finishing normally, because for the deleted users, download files were not being delivered from the Apple servers. I appear to have one still remaining, but I can't find any information on it. I get a login prompt but no more transactions. in the above method. Is there another method I should be checking?

Comment: Hello @VictorEngel .. in some cases I found that the default queue is not go empty until I make a full reset to the device that am working on it ,, maybe this solution will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful, because it suggests part of what is pending exists on the device rather than on Apple's servers. It'd be nice to have an online tool to query the queue separately from the app.

Comment: it did't work for me also here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693872/in-app-purchase-asking-old-account-password-while-restoring can anybody help on this

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes the only solution for this case is to make a full reset to the device