# In-App Purchase Sandbox - Continuous prompt for Apple Login?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I am testing in app purchases in my app right now. I have set up my test accounts in the sandbox on iTunes connect. I am able to sign out of the app store from Settings, then go through the purchase flow on my device with no problems. It prompts for login, I use Existing Account, enter the sandbox test user credentials and am able to purchase or restore products.

The problem is that throughout my session and also when I am bringing the app back from the background, I am continually prompted to re-enter the iTunes app store password. The dialog has my test user id pre-filled and is asking for the password. It also happens when my app is in the background and I am using other apps. Hitting Cancel from here doesn't seem to affect anything negatively.

I am running iOS 7.

Is there something I might be doing wrong with SKPaymentQueue to cause the prompt to be showing again?

Is this only a sandbox issue?

Comment: Are you queueing multiple purchases perhaps ?

Comment: I'm only allowing 1 purchase at a time. On the screen where you purchase, you select one of 3 options, enter credentials, and are then presented with content.

Comment: What code are you using to trigger the purchase ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing something similar...

Comment: same here :/ tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049521/in-app-purchases-sandbox-testing-old-sandbox-users-keep-prompting but didn't work for me, even worse

Comment: Having the similar problem here :(

Comment: yes, it is only sandbox issue

Answer (score 3):

I was running into this. I realized I was not calling finishTransaction.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```