# Can't stop In App Purchase from prompting user's credentials

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I was testing my In App Purchase on iPhone and I did Ray Wenderlich's tutorials to get purchases available. Now I got this error, non stop prompting for user's credentials - even though I looked into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049521/in-app-purchases-sandbox-testing-old-sandbox-users-keep-prompting), but did not help. I restarted device, I hardcoded finish on transactions, I deleted app. I deleted corrupted test user and created new one (with US store set), but now I open app via Xcode and cannot kill alert for credentials. Pressing cancel is only closing it for second and new alert shows up. Even putting wrong password few times is not helping, because of continuously prompt I hardly can choose password remind or anything. Doesn't matter because now it's prompting anywhere, in and outside app. Any idea how to fix it? So I can test with new test user not the deleted one?

update: force restart is causing to prompt continuously, so I'm almost unable to tap anything while testing, because of this in app credentials, for this invalid user... is there a way, to remove from device completely data for corrupted test user?

Comment: May be waiting for some time will help ? or try to change in app purchase bundle identifiers and your app bundle identifier ?

Comment: for now I turned to ios6 simulator, but changing bundle ID would interfere with updating my app in app store. right?

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting changing bundle ID only for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but just incase anyone else finds this, the prompt could be related to this issue:

[Unable to finish unfinished transactions in payment queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028453/unable-to-finish-unfinished-transactions-in-payment-queue/26606565#26606565)