# paymentquue updatedTransactions: not called instead paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished: calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

When I am `restoringCompletedTransactions:` by using the following scenario

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

SKPaymentQueue Delegate not calling `updatedTransactions:` instead it's calling `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` does anybody know about this how to overcome.Let me know if you have any idea.

Thank You in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Apple has listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING-CALLING_THE_PAYMENT_QUEUE___S_RESTORECOMPLETEDTRANSACTIONS_METHOD_DOES_NOT_RESTORE_ANY_PRODUCTS_IN_MY_APPLICATION) a couple reasons why this might fail.

One typical reason: make sure you always finish your transactions, even if they fail.

Answer (score -2):

Change your bundle ID like I said in comment. I requested support to Apple, they promised to look into it but it's been few months nobody contacted me.

Comment: what did you say in the comment? :) could you please update as to what was the workaround

Comment: Changing the bundle ID is not an acceptable answer as it will relist your app on the app store.